# Could this be classed as machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, java

I did a little Google Search on machine learning and got this:

> Machine learning is the ability of a system to learn without being explicitly programmed.

So I decided to attempt to do this on java.

**PS: I will include the code at the end as it is quite long.**

I created a very basic program that let's you input the "Name", "Mass" and "Volume" of an object in a textfield. It then stores this data.

Then, if you - for example - find an object, but you don't know its name, but know it's mass and volume; there is another textfield that enables you to input the "Mass" and "Volume".

Then BASED ON THE INFORMATION IT HAS ALREADY STORED FROM YOUR INPUTS, it can make an estimate on what the object is, then print it out on the console.

The more data there is, the better the estimate.

Just for the record, I made the following functions to print to console, just for fun and so I don't have to type `System.out.print()` or `System.out.println()` all the time.

```
// Print
public static void print(String message) {
    System.out.print(message);
}

public static void print(double number) {
    System.out.print(number);
}



// Print line
public static void println(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}

public static void println(double number) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Here's the meat of the code (using JAVAFX):

```
    // TextField 1
    guessBox = new TextField();
    guessBox.setPromptText("Entry 1 - Entry 2");


    // TextField 2
    storeBox = new TextField();
    storeBox.setPromptText("Name - Entry 1 - Entry 2");


    // Button 1
    guessButton = new Button(" Guess ");


    // Button 2
    storeButton = new Button(" Store ");



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // FUNCTIONALITY                               ////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Object names
    ArrayList<String> matter = new ArrayList<>();

    // Mass
    ArrayList<Double> mass = new ArrayList<>();

    // Volume
    ArrayList<Double> volume = new ArrayList<>();



    // Button functionality
    storeButton.setOnAction( e -> {

        String message = storeBox.getText();
        String[] str = message.split(" - ");

        if(message.isEmpty()) {
            storeBox.setText(message);
        }
        else if(!message.isEmpty() && str.length != 3) {
            storeBox.setText(message);
        }
        else if(!message.isEmpty() && str.length == 3) {
            String na = str[0];
            double ms = Double.parseDouble(str[1]);
            double rd = Double.parseDouble(str[2]);

            matter.add(na);
            mass.add(ms);
            volume.add(rd);


            storeBox.setText("");
        }

    });


    guessButton.setOnAction( e -> {
        String message1 = guessBox.getText();
        String[] str1 = message1.split(" - ");

        if(message1.isEmpty()) {
            guessBox.setText(message1);
        }
        else if(!message1.isEmpty() && str1.length != 2) {
            guessBox.setText(message1);
        }
        else if(!message1.isEmpty() && str1.length == 2) {
            int i = 0;

            double m = Double.parseDouble(str1[0]);
            double r = Double.parseDouble(str1[1]);

            double ratio = m/r;
            double sol = ratio;


            double m1 = mass.get(i);
            double r1 = volume.get(i);

            double ratio1 = m1/r1;
            double sol1 = ratio1 ;

            int len = matter.size() - 1;

            double newArr[] = new double[len + 1];

            while(i <= len) {
                for(int j=0; j<=len; j++) {
                    m1 = mass.get(i);
                    r1 = volume.get(i);

                    ratio1 = m1/r1;
                    sol1 = ratio1;


                    newArr[j] = sol - sol1;


                    i++;
                }
            }

            int p = 0;
            double small = abs(newArr[0]);

            for(int k=0; k<=len; k++) {
                double ans = abs(newArr[k]);
                if(ans < small) {
                    small = ans;
                    p = k;
                }
            }
            println("The object is: " + matter.get(p));


            guessBox.setText("");
        }
    });
```

By the way, the `double sol = ratio` is there simply because I wanted `sol` to be the result of an operation involving `ratio` for better accuracy. But left it at `sol = ratio` for now.

Comment: Can you express the code mathematically?

Comment: @tiredandboreddev - Yeah sure :). Let $m_g$ and $v_g$ be the mass and volume of the user's guess respectively. All the program does is ${m_g \over {v_g}}$ (which is basically the density). Then compares it with the other densities already stored in via subtraction. The smallest result of the subtraction is then considered. Very basic stuff :). Don't know if this is what you meant.

Comment: Just a suggestion. This is predominantly stats/machine learning community. It's better to share algorithm or mathematical model when you're asking a question instead of sharing code. And moreover many people will not be knowing java or a particular programming language.

Comment: @tiredandboreddev - Ahh right, I apologise for that. I wasn't aware, thank you for letting me know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created a basic `nearest neighbor model` and a `predict()` mechanism to find the closest "fit" to your model. I'd call that a simple machine learning algorithm.

You might break out the code doing the modeling and prediction into a separate small method - both to make it more clear to yourself and to readers and also to allow to "override" the methods to use say a quadratic fit instead of a linear one.

Snippet of your `fit()`:

```
        while(i <= len) {
            for(int j=0; j<=len; j++) {
                m1 = mass.get(i);
                r1 = volume.get(i);

                ratio1 = m1/r1;
                sol1 = ratio1;


                newArr[j] = sol - sol1;


                i++;
            }
        }
```

Snippet of your `predict()`:

```
 for(int k=0; k<=len; k++) {
                double ans = abs(newArr[k]);
                if(ans < small) {
                    small = ans;
                    p = k;
                }
            }
```

Comment: So there already is a function that does this?

Comment: Yes *your* function ;)  I just pointed out that you used a kind of `nearest neighbor` model for incrementally fitting the data points as they come in.  You can look it up: your `k` = 1 here (just taking 1 nearest neighbor).